# Yii2- Multiple Bootstrap Modal Items on Same Page

Tags: yii2, bootstrap-modal

I am creating a page which would hold some buttons for creating different model items loaded via modal.

I'm using this code in a view file: `create-all` that belongs to the controller: `ProductsController`

```
        Modal::begin([
            'toggleButton' => [
                'label' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Product',
                'class' => 'btn btn-success'
            ],
            'closeButton' => [
              'label' => 'Close',
              'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right',
            ],
            'size' => 'modal-lg',
        ]);
        $class_products = 'app\models\Products';
        $productModel = new $class_products();

        echo $this->render('/products/create', ['model' => $productModel]);
        Modal::end();

        Modal::begin([
            'toggleButton' => [
                'label' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add branch',
                'class' => 'btn btn-success'
            ],
            'closeButton' => [
              'label' => 'Close',
              'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right',
            ],
            'size' => 'modal-lg',
        ]);
        $class_branch = 'app\models\Branch';
        $branchModel = new $class_branch();

        echo $this->render('/branch/create', ['model' => $branchModel]);
        Modal::end();
```

### `branch/create` code:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Branch */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Create {modelClass}', [
    'modelClass' => 'Branch',
]);
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Branches'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="branch-create">

<?php
//echo Yii::$app->request->getReferrer();
$route = parse_url(Yii::$app->request->getReferrer(), PHP_URL_QUERY);
if ($route == urldecode('r=products%2Fcreate-all'))
print_r ($route);

?>
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

[image: Yii2 Bootstrap Modal Buttons]

The buttons work just fine and a modal loads for both of the  buttons

### Problem

**Add Product** modal adds a new product successfully, but **Add Branch** doesn't. It just refreshes the page.
[image: Modal Loaded]
[image]

Comment: I just gave them some ID, still doesn't work

Comment: Modals looks okey. Outside Modal this form works?

Comment: As an experiment, can you remove your product modal from this file? I bet the branch modal will then work. In any event, can you show your `/products/create` and `/branch/create` code as well as the corresponding controller actions?

Comment: give different id to them.

Comment: it is the exact same code and ids are auto generated by the widget (`id="w0"` `id="w1"` ..) I think that something may be wrong with the **branh/create** action. can you add the related code ?

Comment: Question updated with `branch/create` code. It has nothing special. the code was generated from yii2's Gii generator.

Comment: You are directly rendering the view from the model. So inorder to post data to the action,you need to specify the `action` in the activeform you are rendering.

Answer (score 1):

An attempt to solve your issue:

As far as I know, simply rendering view file inside the view, will not post data to the controller, unless you specify the action inside the form which you are rendering.

So inside the `_form.php`

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
       'action'=>'your_path_to_the_url',
    ]); ?>
```

You can also make an ajax submission from the form and handle the ajax data using `Yii::$app->request->isAjax`

This is just an idea. I have not seen your controller code nor your forms. Still a wild guess of the problem. See this will help you or not.